# How do you find the voltage across a capacitor at time t= 0 and t = infinity?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, dc, time

Here is a diagram of the circuit, I am confused about problems a and b.

[image]

How do I go about solving these two problems? Thanks!

By the way you don't have to tell me the answer, I just want to know how I should think about it, or any helpful hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

A capacitor's voltage-current response is governed by:
\begin{equation}
I = C \frac{dV_c}{dt}
\end{equation}

At \$t = 0\$: think about what happens when you integrate in the limit as \$dt \rightarrow 0\$ (i.e. what is a capacitor unable to do with respect to really fast transients?)

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{0^-}^{\delta} I dt = \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} C \int_{0^-}^{\delta} \frac{d V_c}{dt} dt
\end{equation}
Note that this equation does **not** imply \$I(0^+) = 0\$; it only provides a mathematical "weak" guarantee that it's integral doesn't change over the infinitesimal.

At \$t \rightarrow \infty\$, think of what happens when all transient behavior goes away (\$\frac{d <value>}{dt} = 0\$).

Comment: would it be that at t =0 and t> infinity, no current can flow through the capacitor? and so therefore I would equal 0, and so 0 = 1f (dV/dt), and therefore the voltage across the capacitor would be zero in both cases?

Comment: Im not too sure..I guess that would mean that there would be a voltage across the capacitor right before t=0? would the answer be 1 V?

Comment: No, there is not 1V across the capacitor at \$t=0\$. Also, there is not 0V across the capacitor at \$t \rightarrow \infty\$. You need to take KCL and KVL into account.

Comment: Technically there is no DC current "flowing" through a capacitor (at least in an ideal capacitor).  Charge accumulates on one side and an equal amount of charge is forced out the other side.  Because of this charge imbalance you can measure a voltage.

Comment: @Nedd of course there's no DC current flowing through a capacitor: the voltage-current response for a DC current would requite \$\frac{d V}{dt} = const\$, so V would tend to infinity (positive or negative), which just can't happen. That doesn't mean there isn't current flowing through the capacitor: see [Displacement current](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current).

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to understand here is that the voltage across a capacitor cannot change instantaneously. You know there's going to be an exponential decay. This means you can divide the solution into three steps:

1. DC circuit analysis before the switching event (initial condition)
2. DC circuit analysis a long time after the switching event (final condition)
3. Determine the rate of decay (time constant)

Steps 1 and 2 will answer parts a, b, and d of your problem, as well as the second half of c. All three steps are needed to answer the first half of c.

Answer (score 0):

1) At the instant of turn-on the [discharged] capacitor will look like a short circuit. What's the voltage across a short circuit?

2) When the capacitor is fully charged it'll look like an open circuit. What's the voltage across an open circuit?

Answer (score 0):

For a more simplified format (with out the calculus), first find the circuit's time constant RC, which is also known as "tau".  Lets use this as "t", so then t=RC.  With t in seconds.

Once you know t the voltage on C can be more easily calculated. The voltage on C will change by 63% of the applied voltage (applied across RC) after each t time period.  This works for charging or discharging. (In discharging you could say the voltage is at 37%, however this is the same as saying a 63% decrease.)

For example if t = 1 second, and the available voltage applied to RC was 10v DC, the voltage on C would be 6.3v after 1 second.  Then in the next 1 second C would further charge to 6.3 + 63% of the remaining voltage difference. In this case (6.3 + (10-6.3) x 63%)).  In this form you could argue that the voltage on C will never fully reach 10v.

To be a bit more accurate you could use 63.2%.

Here is a wiki reference for RC Time Constant: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant

Answer (score 0):

Voltage across a capacitor cannot change instantenously, so:

$$V_0(0^-)=0 \Longrightarrow V_c(0^-)=V_c(0^+)=0 \ \therefore \ V_c(0)=0V $$

You can write the following diff. equation for other values of Vc:

$$R3.C\frac {dV_c}{dt}+V_c=V_0$$

Solution of this first order linear diff. equation gives:

$$V_c(t)=1+ke^{-t/C}$$

If you use the initial value you find \$k=-1\$ and \$ t \rightarrow \infty \Longrightarrow V_c=1V \$.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitor voltage can't change instantly, since that would require infinite current.  Therefore the capacitor voltage at T = 0 is whatever it was just before T = 0.

At T = ∞, everything is assumed to be in steady state.  If the circuit is purely DC, then no current will be flowing thru any capacitor and you can replace all caps with open circuits for the purpose of finding the voltages of the circuit.